# I got an error "Return value must be of the type int, array returned" when trying to count rows of imported excel file

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I'm trying to count rows of imported excel file (first sheet only, I do it with DataTestImport.php), but I got an error: "Return value of App\Imports\DataTestImport::getRowCount1() must be of the type int, array returned". What should I do to solve that error?

DataTestController.php

```
$import = new DataTestImport;
print_r('Row count: ' . (int)implode($import->getRowCount1()));
```

DataTestImport.php

```
protected $import;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->import = new TestImport;
}

public function getRowCount1(): array
{
    return [
        0 => $this->import->getRowCount(),
    ];
}
```

TestImport.php

```
private $i = 0;

public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        ** a lot of codes here **

        ++$this->i;
    }
}

public function getRowCount(): int
{
    return $this->i;
}
```

Comment: The error seems pretty straightforward. What issue are you having? `[
        0 => $this->import->getRowCount(),
    ]` is an array.

Comment: @user3783243 I want to count rows in the first sheet only, what should I do to do it while keeping the "0 =>"?

Comment: That is an array you are making, which the error tells you it doesn't want. You can't concatenate an array.

Comment: *I'm using WithMultipleSheet

Comment: I don't know what that means. Read `must be of the type int`, you can't send back an array... or you need to modify the usages of the function call to work with array rather than int.

Comment: @user3783243 I change getRowCount1(): int to getRowCount1(): array, convert it to int, but I got Row count: 0

Comment: So the function not working is another issue are having? You need to state the question you have.. if it is about the error it sounds like that has been resolved. I don't know what library you are using here so can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Just return int as you promise in function declaration

```
public function getRowCount1(): int
{
    return $this->import->getRowCount();
}
```

Comment: it also give me Row count: 0

Comment: I do it and convert it to int with (int)implode($import->getRowCount1()) but it returned 0

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward, this function is clearly returning a PHP array, while the return type is an int (`public function... : int`):

```
public function getRowCount1(): int
{
    return [
        0 => $this->import->getRowCount(),
    ];
}
```

So you would probably want to change the type to an array instead:

```
public function getRowCount1(): array
{
    return [
        0 => $this->import->getRowCount(),
    ];
}
```

Comment: I do it and convert it to int with (int)implode($import->getRowCount1()) but it returns this result: Row count: 0

Comment: Replace it with:
print_r('Row count: ' . $import->getRowCount1()[0]);

Comment: sorry, but it still returning Row count: 0

Comment: I'm sorry too, but your question poorly phrased and we can't debug everything for you. I answered your original question, but it might be that `collection` method is not being called. please debug your own program and then come with the results .

Comment: yeah the collection method is not being called, I change "private $i = 0;" to 5 and it'll return Row count: 5

Comment: This is what I follow: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/objects.html#getters